# How do I optimize an image that is already compressed?

Tags: image, optimization, google-pagespeed

According to [PSI's](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fjimmydance.com&tab=mobile) I need to optimize one more [image](https://jimmydance.com/images/belly-dancer-sydney.jpg). The thing is I already did! Why this occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not complain about that image any more. PSI caches results for some time, maybe you fixed the problem and didn't wait long enough for PSI to update?

Besides, Google does not get to decide if an image is compressed enough or not... Sometimes it's just worth the extra milliseconds to get a nicer image - and sometimes it's not. It's just an indicator - try not to focus too much on getting it to 100%.